# Any studies showing generic currency symbol is understandable by most people?

Tags: symbols, currency

As you may probably know, there's a generic currency symbol supposed to replace specific currencies. So, instead of using $, €, £, or ¥ I can use **¤** which is the [generic currency sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_sign_(typography)).

The sign was encoded for computers in 1972, added to ISO 646 that year and it even has its own **[HTML entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML)** clearly labeled for what is intended to be: `&curren;` , so it's evident efforts were made to make this symbol a norm.

However, a quick study we did shown what we expected: out of 30 users between 18 and 45 years old, only one person could recognize this symbol as the symbol for currency. Study was done in Buenos Aires, Argentina, so there's some space for localization issues. Still, even accounting for localization, the results are quite demonstrative of the hypothesis we had.

Thus, my question is: is there any study that effectively shows this symbol is recognized by a relatively broad audience in any country? And if not, is there a **GENERIC** symbol with better recognition (it's very important for us not to use an specific currency)?

Comment: Aside from the fact that I (and presumably a large number of people) would not recognize what that symbol means. I don't think ¤ even resembles the true symbol (seen in the picture on the Wiki article). It looks more like a small square...

Comment: Do you use glasses by any chance? We got that answer by 7 out of 30 people, 6 of them using glasses, which would also prove high legibility issues

Comment: Nope, no corrective lenses. Not quite 20/20 (don't remember exact numbers) but never had vision issues. FWIW, doesn't resemble the real symbol on any main browser (IE, FF, Chrome) but looks worst in chrome. I can tell it isn't just a box but looks a lot like a box with distorted edges. May just be the font used on UX.SE/Wikipedia I haven't tested elsewhere.

Comment: I always thought that was a mini-sun. Do you really need a study to tell you the average John/Jane Doe won't recognize that as the 'generic currency symbol'?

Comment: Relevant question: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/83894/can-the-symbol-be-safely-considered-as-universal-when-making-a-graphic-depic/83942#83942

Comment: @Insane, I don't know your work methodology, but in our case, we always strive to provide as much data as possible to our clients, using research , scoentific methods or available paper/studies. Our opinion without any objective support is absolutely irrelevant. We're paid to do that and have no plans to change our methodology in the near future. Thank you for your input anyways

Comment: I got to know the symbol by accidently making a password with it (shift+num, didn't care what symbol it was). It was hell trying to write it using phone instead of pc keyboard. Ended up googling it, copy it, then paste it into the password field.

Answer (score 5):

For a generic symbol

A pile (or two)

[*of coins*](http://www.freeiconspng.com/free-images/coin-icon-3814)

And I (in the UK) wouldn't recognise the ISO symbol

Comment: Brilliant solution. I hope such an icon will be included in the fontawesome package in the future.